# how to run ionic app that works with api from another laravel app in real device?

Tags: laravel, api, ionic-framework

the idea that i have laravel app and i want to make a mobile app that work with api from my laravel app . i succed to do this it's works perfectly in browser but when i want to test it with a real device or an emulator isn't work even i use the address ip of my computer to get the api from laravel app
instead of localhost
Sorry for my english and any one have idea for this problem please ?
this my code in ionic  provider where i get the api

```
 public token:any;
  constructor(public storage:Storage ,public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }
  login(credentials){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
      headers.append('Accept','application/json');
      headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
       headers.append('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
        this.http.post('http://192.168.1.11:8101/api/auth/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            let data = res.json();
            this.token = data.token;
            localStorage.setItem('token',data.access_token);

            resolve(data);
   }, (err) => {
            reject(err);

          });  });
```

Comment: Sometimes your web server firewall restrict your local site to access from other host in the same private network. Check your web server settings.

Comment: i didn't know what you realy mean how i can check it ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared is not laravel code, this is your ionic code.
As you are saying your code is working in web app and not working in mobile platform with the same code. Then perhaps you are missing something from 
`config.xml` file.

Please update this in your config.xml as it works fine for me.

```
<author email="alex@artisanfertility.com" href="https://artisanfertility.com">Alex Steinleitner</autho
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
  <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: i already have this code in my config.xml and sorry yes the code is from my ionic app i edit this in the post

Comment: Yes it work's in web perfectly i can login and do all the fonctionnality but the problem is with emulator or a real device

Comment: do you have cordova-plugin-whitelist installed?
Install this and check this it should work fine. 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/